# Impossible to install python packages - SSL error

Tags: python, ssl, pip, package

I installed ubuntu for Windows on my corporate laptop.

I have a problem with installing python libraries.

When i use `sudo pip3 install <libraryname>` command

I receive this message (example with django but similar message for all packages)

How to fix this issue? I have the impression that my computer does not allow the SSL connection.

[image]

Comment: I would suggest reinstalling python to ensure the package manager is properly functional, I have added an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Update and Refresh Repository Lists, Open a terminal window, and enter the following:

```
sudo apt update
```

Step 2: Install Supporting Software
The software-properties-common package gives you better control over your package manager by letting you add PPA (Personal Package Archive) repositories. Install the supporting software with the command:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
```

Step 3: Add Deadsnakes PPA
Deadsnakes is a PPA with newer releases than the default Ubuntu repositories. Add the PPA by entering the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
```

The system will prompt you to press enter to continue. Do so, and allow it to finish. Refresh the package lists again:

```
sudo apt update
```

Step 4: Install Python 3
Now you can start the installation of Python 3.8 with the command:

```
sudo apt install python3.8
```

Allow the process to complete and verify the Python version was installed sucessfully::

```
python ––version
```

next try and install your pip package once you have verified python is properly installed.

Comment: I tried your method but it didn't solve the problem. Is it possible that the settings of my laptop is blocking the connection?

Comment: What do you mean "it didn't solve the problem", did you get any errors in the console? Run all of the commands above, then after run `sudo pip3 install Django`.

Comment: after running the commands above, I tried `sudo pip3 install django` but I still receive the same messages you can see above.

Comment: try with a capital D `sudo pip3 install Django`

Comment: it has no effect. and it's not related to django. I cannot install any package, whatever package to install I get exactly the same message.

Comment: uninstall python completely, remove it from your computer, then reinstall Python using answer above. `I cannot install any package` is likely due to a corrupt installation.

Answer (score 0):

Add a flag to ignore the verification of SSL certificates:

```
sudo pip3 install <package-name> config --global http.sslVerify false
```

I would also suggest updating pip and setuptools as a general advice, which could help with further errors:

```
 sudo pip3 install pip setuptools
```

Comment: problem still present. Do you have an other idea?